# HTML rendering in real time : Winforms

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms

As a student, I am trying to build an application. However, I encounter a difficulty. I would like to make my application into two parts. A first where there is a code editor to type HTML and another that shows the rendering of the page in real time.

How to make the second part? It should refresh the view for each change of code in the editor.

I thank all those who could help me. (Sorry for my english, I'm from Switzerland).

Best regards

Comment: Use *Webbrowser Control*

Comment: I think that you're trying something like https://jsfiddle.net/. Google it, maybe you can find an implementation you can take as a base. I strongly recommend to choose other technology different that WinForms.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses. The winforms technology doesn't depend on me unfortunately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a simple Winforms application with a multiline [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) and a [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) control. Just attatch your [TextChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event as follows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Size = new Size(800, 600);

        mTextBox = new TextBox();
        mTextBox.Multiline = true;
        mTextBox.Font = new Font("Consolas", 10);
        mTextBox.TextChanged += textbox_TextChanged;
        mTextBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        mTextBox.Height = 400;

        Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
        splitter.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;

        mWebBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        mWebBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;

        Controls.Add(mTextBox);
        Controls.Add(splitter);
        Controls.Add(mWebBrowser);

        mTextBox.Text = "<html>\r\n<h1>Testing!</h1>\r\n</html>";
    }

    void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mWebBrowser.DocumentText = mTextBox.Text;
    }

    WebBrowser mWebBrowser;
    TextBox mTextBox;
}
```

Comment: Great, this solution seems even better. I'll try it as soon as possible. Thank you :)

Comment: I edited the code snippet. You have a functional example working ;-)

Comment: unfortunately can't because of my reputation

Answer (score 0):

Its actually quite simple, if youre already writing out your html file, you just need to add the webbrowser control.

When you have the Web browser control on the page you need to give it a source \ url to go to.

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("location of your html file here");
```

Now depending on where your saving your html page is where it needs to pick it up from. I would suggest that you have a textbox on the page which tells the application where to save the file too, but will also server as where to pick the html page up from.

I wouldn't recommend having the page update each time you make a change, I would recommend that you have a button to actually do the refresh for you as if you use the TextChanged event youre going to be calling your page every single character and not actually give it time to load.

so, every save, you should update the view and not before otherwise youre going to give yourself a big issue.

Comment: Okay, thank you for all that informations.
I could refresh every X seconds, maybe?

Comment: i wouldnt recommend it, i would refresh it on command as if youre writing html and it automatically refreshes if youve not finished our elements it could make you think youve done something wrong.